# Drag and drop Text Box to List Box

Tags: vb.net, drag-and-drop, mousedown

I'm working on a VB.net(2015) code that would allow me to drag and drop from a text box to a list box.

I've set up the code below, and set the allow drop in the list box to true.

I’m able to drag the text to the list box, but it doesn’t appear in the list box.

Looking at the code below I’m not sure what piece I’ve left out, are there any recommendations or suggestions on what can be done?

```
Public Class PotluckParty

Private Sub enterFoodTextBox_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles enterFoodTextBox.MouseDown

    enterFoodTextBox.DoDragDrop(enterFoodTextBox.Text, DragDropEffects.Move)

End Sub

Private Sub SaladListBox_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles SaladListBox.DragDrop

    SaladListBox.Text &= e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString
    enterFoodTextBox.Text = ""

End Sub

Private Sub SaladListBox_DragEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles SaladListBox.DragEnter
    If (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text)) Then
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move

    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: ListBox does not have a meaningful Text property, it shows a list.  Consider its Items.Add() method instead.  And let the IntelliSense popup help you fall in the pit of success.

Comment: Excellent, your advice worked.  Thank you very much Hans.